# How to pass a local variable to a user-defined function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions, local-variables

I am processing a pandas dataframe `df`. Depending on certain conditions within `df`, I want to pass `df` (1) either to the user defined function `filter()` or (2) to `calculate_Result()`.

The code for the condition is:

```
if df.Col1.str.contains("yes").sum() > 0:
    df = filter_df
    filter() # Loop
else:
    df = calculate_df
    calculate_result() # End
```

However, I am yielding a `UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment.`

I keep getting this error also when I put the `df = calculate_df` & `df = filter_df` assignments in the function definitions itself:

```
def filter():
    df = filter_df
    ...
```

and

```
def calculate_results():
    df = calculate_df()
    ...
```

no matter where I put the assignments, I am yielding `UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment.`

How to correctly pass a local variable to a user defined function in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't to do with passing a variable to a function.

You have used the name `df` to refer both to a global module - in `df.Col1...` and as the result of `filter_df`. That causes the error you see.

Use a different name for the local variable.

Comment: I am not quite sure if i understand. If certain conditions in df are met, I want to rename it and continue working with it in function def1. If the conditions are not met, I want to continue working with it in function def2. Therefore, the name df has to be the same (1) when checking the condition and (2) within the function. I want to pass the same dataframe to different functions depending on a condition within the dataframe.

Comment: No. That makes no sense, and bears no relation to the code you have posted or the problem you are having. "Renaming" a variable in one function has *absolutely nothing at all* to do with how you pass it to another function. You should post enough code so we can see what you are actually doing.